# FireBase Callback method never gets called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The callback method never gets called.   Am I doing something wrong here?

```
String FirebaseRefer = Constants.Client+"/"+Constants.firebaseProjects+"/"+Constants.ProjectName+"/xyz";
            final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseRefer);

            ref.keepSynced(true);

            ref.child("mockChild").push().setValue("dummyValue", new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {

//This never gets called.

}
```

More info :- The following code used to work..
Only after I added setChild().push() etc it stopped working.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Comment: Where is the value change eventlistener.

Comment: @RajendranNadar As an argument of onDataChange.

Comment: Try removing the final keywork from line 2

Comment: final keyword has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo You are right. I tried removing the final. It doesnt make a difference.

Comment: @AlexMamo I doubt whether the listener that I am setting is wrong or something.

Comment: @AlexMamo please see the answer.

Comment: @RajendranNadar please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the listener object(anonymous) that I was passing to the method was of the wrong Class. (Surprisingly it didn't show me an error)

The right code looks something like this:-

```
  ref.child("mockChild").push().setValue("dummyValue", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Thats what i was saying you need a value event listener.